# html内の値をコード.gsで変数に入れて使う方法

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Google Apps Scriptで作成したindex.htmlにセレクトボックスを作成しました。
県名を選択したときに、その値をコード.gs内で変数に入れて使いたいのですが、どのようにして値を取得するのか、また、その値をコード.gsで使う方法が分かりません。

index.html

```html
<form name="kenform">
    <select name="ken" onChange="kakunin()">
        <option value="県名1">県名1</option>
        <option value="県名2">県名2</option>
        <option value="県名3">県名3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

更にここで取得した値（県名）をGAS側の「SHEET_NAME」変数に代入して使いたい場合はどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

コード.gs

```js
var SPREAD_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var SHEET_NAME = 
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREAD_ID);
sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
```

どなたか、アドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

`google.script.run` が使えると思います。

[HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions  \|  Apps Script  \|  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="kenform">
      <select name="ken" onChange="google.script.run.kakunin(this.value)">
        <option value="県名1">県名1</option>
       　<option value="県名2">県名2</option>
        <option value="県名3">県名3</option>
       </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function kakunin(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

ログ

```
[16-07-29 18:20:43:432 JST] 県名2
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
index.gsで取得した「県名2」ですが、例えばindex.gsに「var SHEET_NAME」という変数があった場合に、その変数に値を入れるにはどういうコードにすれば良いのでしょうか。